# Is it possible to show empty slots using StorCli?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, storcli

I have been searching for a while but I couldn't find any way to show "empty/available/free" drive-slots connected to a LSI card using `storcli`.
I don't even know if the hardware supports it.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you guys!

Comment: I'm open to use others tools if I could get that info without need to check the server and count "turned off lights"